# Continuously Monitoring ICY Stream Metadata (Title, Artist)

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

This script is called every minute, but I want it to run continuously instead of making that many requests to the radio station and I think that `urllib.request` can be replaced with the requests module. If possible I would like also to store the title and the artist separately.
It would be great if someone can help me optimize this and if there are also other things to optimize.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import struct
import urllib.request as urllib
from pathlib import Path
import re

CONFIG = [
    ["CHARTS", "https://icepool.silvacast.com/charts.mp3"],
    ["HITS", "https://icepool.silvacast.com/hits.mp3"]
]

PATH = "/tools/"

for INDEX in range(len(CONFIG)):
    ENCODING = "UTF-8"
    REQUEST = urllib.Request(CONFIG[INDEX][1], headers={"Icy-MetaData": 1})
    RESPONSE = urllib.urlopen(REQUEST)
    #print(RESPONSE.headers)
    META_INT = int(RESPONSE.headers["icy-metaint"])
    for _ in range(10): # TITLE may be empty initially, try several times
        RESPONSE.read(META_INT)
        META_DATA = RESPONSE.read(struct.unpack("B", RESPONSE.read(1))[0] * 16).rstrip(b"\0")
        #print(META_DATA)
        TITLE_DATA = re.search(br"StreamTitle='([^']*)';", META_DATA)
        #print(TITLE_DATA)
        if TITLE_DATA:
            TITLE = TITLE_DATA.group(1)
            if TITLE:
                break
    else:
        break
    SONG = TITLE.decode(ENCODING).strip().replace("", "")
    SONG = re.sub("(@.)$", "", SONG)
    #print(SONG)
    
    if not Path("{}{}.txt".format(PATH,CONFIG[INDEX][0])).exists():
        Path("{}{}.txt".format(PATH,CONFIG[INDEX][0])).touch()
    with open(file = "{}{}.txt".format(PATH,CONFIG[INDEX][0]), mode = "r+", encoding = "UTF-8") as LIST_FILE:
        SONG_LIST = [LINE.strip() for LINE in LIST_FILE]
        #print(SONG_LIST)
        if SONG not in SONG_LIST:
            LIST_FILE.write(SONG + "\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

## a loop variable is not a constant

```
for INDEX in range...
```

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you please not do that.

And I ask, rather than phrase it `for index in ...`,
you just go with the usual variable name of `i`.
Or much better, use tuple unpacking:

```
for station_name, url in CONFIG:
```

Similarly downcase `request`, `response`, the title and meta vars, etc.

```
    #print(RESPONSE.headers)
```

This was valuable at one point.
But now you're ready for colleagues to review and interact
with code that's merged down to `main`.
It is time to delete commented code.

---

## appropriate datastructure

```
CONFIG = [
    ["CHARTS", "https://icepool.silvacast.com/charts.mp3"],
    ["HITS", "https://icepool.silvacast.com/hits.mp3"]
]
```

You might find a `dict` more convenient than a `list`.

If you *do* stick with a list, better to have a list of 2-tuples.

---

## magic number

```
    for _ in range(10):
```

Kudos, the `_` is nice.
And kudos for using `.urlopen()` so you read only the *front* of a giant MP3 stream.

The [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
ten deserves a name, perhaps `MAX_SCANNED_INTERVALS`.

After reading `.headers["icy-metaint"]` I can certainly understand
why you might assign the value to `meta_int`.
But ICY chose a regrettable abbreviation, which sounds like "integer",
so you should prefer to spell out `meta_interval`.

The final `else: break` does nothing for that
[for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for).
It could be safely elided, and should be.
(Or, maybe it's a typo that uses the wrong amount of indent?)

---

## simplify repeated expression

This is just painful:

```
    if not Path("{}{}.txt".format(PATH, CONFIG[INDEX][0])).exists():
        Path("{}{}.txt".format(PATH, CONFIG[INDEX][0])).touch()
    with open(file = "{}{}.txt".format(PATH, CONFIG[INDEX][0]), mode...
```

Assign a temp var already!

There's a common subexpression we can pull out:

```
    text_file = Path("{}{}.txt".format(PATH, CONFIG[INDEX][0])
```

Or better:

```
    PATH = Path("/tools/")
    ...
    text_file = PATH / f"{CONFIG[INDEX][0]}.txt"
```

and better still:

```
    text_file = PATH / f"{station_name}.txt"
```

which at last is an expression that is human readable.
Now we can use it three times:

```
    if not text_file.exists():
        text_file.touch()
    with open(text_file, mode...
```

```
        SONG_LIST = [LINE.strip() for LINE in LIST_FILE]
```

Given that we're creating this so we can test whether `song` is `in` the container,
it would be better to construct a `set` rather than a `list`.

This last portion of the script is a nice discrete bit of functionality,
and would benefit from being broken out as a `def maybe_append_song_name( ... ):`
helper function.

---

## loop forever

> want it to run continuously

First, take the entire `for` loop body
and package it up as a `def read_song_name(url):` helper function.

Now you can conveniently loop forever:

```
    from time import sleep

    DELAY = 20  # seconds

    while True:
        for station_name, url in CONFIG:
            read_song_name(url)
        sleep(DELAY)
```

(Or perhaps `for _, url in CONFIG:`, since we ignore the name.)

That approach re-creates the "run a short-lived script and then
infinitely restart" setup you currently use.
Hopefully ten intervals (ten chunks of audio data)
corresponds to less than twenty seconds of playback -- else we'd
be re-requesting same old data multiple times.

As an alternative approach, maybe you want to keep that `.urlopen()` response handle?
If you hang on to it forever, within a `while True:` loop,
you can just keep reading and reading until you see another title header.
This has the significant advantage of showing new title ASAP when it changes.
It *is* too bad that we're not playing the received audio data though,
and merely discard it.

If possible, request the crummiest low-fidelity stream possible,
since all we really want is the icecast headers.

Right now you're pointing your favorite stream player desktop app
at silvacast.com.
You might consider pointing it at 127.0.0.1 localhost,
and having this python code make the MP3 audio data
available on a localhost port.
That way you'd only be downloading the stream over the WAN a single time.

Using the `requests` module (with `stream=True` here) is usually preferable over `urllib`,
just because it is a more convenient API to call into.
What happens on the wire between client and server will be much the same.
The key to efficiency is that, instead of closing the stream
and re-opening it when script re-runs a minute later,
you want the script to run for "a long time" (hours?)
and keep downloading MP3 + metadata from that single TCP stream.

Comment: As an alternative approach, maybe you want to keep that .urlopen() response handle? If you hang on to it forever, within a while True: loop, you can just keep reading and reading until you see another title header. This has the significant advantage of showing new title ASAP when it changes. It is too bad that we're not playing the received audio data though, and merely discard it.

Can you give me an example code of this also with requests.session ?

Comment: You already have the code in the OP. Instead of exiting upon finding a valid title, simply keep reading and reading and reading, forever, displaying new title when you notice its text has changed.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but then only one station will be checked forever. How can I do this for all stations?

Comment: Oh. Honestly, I fear it is more complex than you're keen to get into at this point. So I recommend you spawn a python child which focuses on the CHARTS station, and spawn a second child that focuses on the HITS station. But fine, let's say we're signed up for advanced networking nonsense. You will want to use the [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) module. Or, almost as good, since both connections keep streaming at some low-ish rate: use non-blocking I/O. That is, sleep(.1), then read() from one, read() from the other, and loop forever. Empty read? That's OK! Keep looping.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Can I accomplish this also with requests.get or session.get instead of .urlopen?

Comment: You will be consuming a `stream=True` `requests` stream, yes. A typical call would consume an entire HTML document from the server, but in your case you need to keep looping as you read small buffers of audio data, since the audio stream is never ending.

Comment: OK, should I use Thread, ThreadPoolExecutor or AsyncIO to accomplish this?

Comment: There seems little need for a pool. I didn't mention any of those technologies, though you are certainly free to use them, they can fit into a nice solution. I did suggest using select() in a single process, to notice non-blocking file descriptors that are ready to read. Asyncio is a related but different approach to tackling the same problem. I also suggested simplifying matters by using your existing code twice, in two child processes that each do blocking reads. If you prefer to use existing code twice by spawning a pair of worker threads that do blocking reads, then more power to you!

Comment: Ok I will try and then post my solution. What do you mean by
This is just painful:

    if not Path("{}{}.txt".format(PATH, CONFIG[INDEX][0])).exists():
        Path("{}{}.txt".format(PATH, CONFIG[INDEX][0])).touch()
    with open(file = "{}{}.txt".format(PATH, CONFIG[INDEX][0]), mode...

Assign a temp var already!

Comment: Yesterday I updated the answer to illustrate several ways one might DRY up the code and make it more readable by extracting common subexpressions into a new temp var.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that requests should be preferred over bare urllib. Replacing your stream calls with a requests wrapper, you need to issue `stream=True`. To start, this could look like

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import struct
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Iterator

from urllib3 import HTTPResponse

from requests import Session


def consume_stream(stream: HTTPResponse) -> Iterator[tuple[str, str]]:
    chunk_size = 16
    metachunks, = struct.unpack("B", stream.read(1))
    binary = stream.read(chunk_size * metachunks).rstrip(b'\0')

    pat = re.compile(
        '''(?x)
        (?P<key>[^'=]+)   # Key: everything before the =
        ='
        (?P<value>[^']*)  # Value assumed everything within quotes
        ';
        '''
    )

    for match in pat.finditer(binary.decode()):
        yield match.group('key'), match.group('value')


def fetch_metadata(session: Session, section: str, tries: int = 10) -> dict[str, str]:
    with session.get(
        url=f'https://icepool.silvacast.com/{section}.mp3',
        stream=True,
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        prelude_length = int(resp.headers['icy-metaint'])

        for _ in range(tries):
            resp.raw.read(prelude_length)
            meta = dict(consume_stream(resp.raw))
            if 'StreamTitle' in meta:
                return meta

    # Give up and return partial result
    return meta


def main() -> None:
    with Session() as session:
        session.headers = {
            'Icy-Metadata': '1',
            'Accept': 'audio/mpeg',
        }

        for section in ('charts', 'hits'):
            pprint(fetch_metadata(session, section))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which is roughly equivalent to what you have, but with a regex expanded for legibility.